# Reverse a string "Hello World" to "World Hello", What is wrong?

Tags: c

I am trying to make "Hello World" to "World Hello".
But the code is not working properly the way I wanted it to behave.
See the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct llnode
{
    char *info;
    struct llnode *next;
};

typedef struct llnode NODE;

int main()
{
    char msg[50],word[10],*str;
    int i=0,length=0,j=0;
    NODE *ptr,*front=NULL,*temp,*last=NULL;

    //printf("Enter the sentence: ");
    str= "Hello World"; //fgets(msg,sizeof(msg),stdin);

    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        if((str[i]==' ')||(str[i]=='\n'))
        {
            word[j]='\0';
            j=0;
            ptr=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
            ptr->info=word;
            ptr->next=NULL;

            if(front==NULL)
            {
                front=ptr; // only change the value of front here;
            }
            else
            {
                temp=front;
                while((temp->next)!=NULL)
                {
                    temp=temp->next;
                }
                temp->next=ptr;
            }
            printf("\n##%s\n",front->info); // prints thewords and not
            //the first word
        }
        else
        {
            word[j]=str[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    temp=front;
    while(temp)
    {
        length++;
        printf("%s ",temp->info);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\nLength of Linked List(or, number of words): %d\n",length);

    i=0;
    printf("\n************************\n");

    while(i<length)
    {
        temp=front;
        while(temp->next!=last)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        last=temp;
        printf("%s ",temp->info);
    i++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Ben: It's not homework, but yesterday I was going through one website, there I found this question. So thought of to write the program. But it's not happening.

Comment: Moved code across to SO - please don't put your code on other sites then link to them, we want SO to be useful even if the entire rest of the internet falls in a black hole. Oh, yeah, and you may want to learn to indent a little better, I fixed that for you as well :-)

Comment: Can you post a link to the original question as you found it?

Comment: The problem is you are not adding the last word into the linked list. After your `while(str[i]!='\0')` exits you should add the last collected word to the list.

Comment: Here's a hint: You don't need to build a linked list to solve this problem - and it's a lot simpler than it sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with the code:

You are using a single word array to read all the words. So, when you read "Hello", you read into the word array, print "##Hello" and store the pointer to the word array as front->info. Then, you OVERWRITE the word array with World. Also, please note that you NEVER add a node with the word "World" because you exit the loop as soon as you encounter the '\0'. So, your linked list contains only one node. But, there is a problem, since you stored a pointer to the word array in the first node and since the word array has been overwritten with "World", when you exit the loop, there is only one node in the list and the info of this node is word array which contains "World" and not "Hello" like it once did. So, I guess this explains the output?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `strtok()` for this purpose. See this [example](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/strtok.html), just replace the hashtags with spaces and print backwards. This is by far the easiest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like homework... but, for starters, if your delimiters are a space and a newline:

```
if((str[i]==' ')||(str[i]=='\n'))
```

...then a string that doesn't contain a space or a newline at the end will never parse the last element:

```
str= "Hello World"; //fgets(msg,sizeof(msg),stdin);
```

...so my guess is that you're never even putting "World" into the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did this one

```
   /**
    I am a boy -> boy a am I

    */
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main()
{
    int i, j, n, temp, temp_i, cnt;
    //char *array = "Samsung";
    char array[1000];
    char newarr[strlen(array)];
    printf("Enter The String: \n");
    gets(array);

    for(i = (strlen(array)-1), n = 0, j = 0; i >= 0; i--)
    {
     if( array[i] != ' ')
     {
         n++;
     }
     else
     {
         temp = n;
         temp_i = i;
         for(n = 0; n <= temp; n++)
         {
           //  i = i + 1;
             newarr[j++] = array[i++];
         }
         i = temp_i;
         n = 0;
     }

     if(i == 0)
     {
         newarr[j++] = ' ';
         temp = n;
         temp_i = i;
         for(n = 0; n <= temp; n++)
         {
           //  i = i + 1;
             newarr[j++] = array[i++];
         }
         i = temp_i;
         n = 0;
     }


     //newarr[j++] = array[i];
    }
    newarr[j] = '\0';
    cnt = 0;
    for(j = 0; j <= (strlen(newarr)-1); j++)/*This is not required just do some R n D*/
    {
        newarr[j] = newarr[++cnt];
    }
   //  printf("The first element is %c \n", newarr[1]);
    puts(newarr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In Python `print(' '.join(list(string.split(' '))[::-1]))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution with c++11 . Which reverses the words as required and prints it on screen.

```
vector<string> words;
string str = "hello world c++11";

size_t current = 0;
size_t found = str.find(" ");

while(found != string::npos)
{
    words.push_back(str.substr(current, found - current));

    current = found + 1;
    found = str.find(" ",current);
}

words.push_back(str.substr(current));

std::ostream_iterator<string> Display_iter(std::cout," ") ;
std::copy(words.rbegin(), words.rend(), Display_iter);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First reverse the entire string ( it gives like "dlrow olleh")
2) and then call/reverse word from first character until space/endOfString encounters.
3) It gives desired output.

Answer (score 0):

#include 
  #include

int main() {

```
  char *src = "I am a boy";
  char dest[50][50];
  int idx = 0;
  int priv_idx = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  while(src[i] != '\0') {
      if(src[i] == ' ') {
          if(priv_idx == idx) {
              idx ++;
              j = 0;
          }
          i++;
          continue;
      }
      *(*(dest + idx) + j) = src[i];
      i++;
      j++;
      priv_idx = idx;
  }

  for (i = idx; i>=0; --i) {
      printf("%s\n\r",dest[i]);
  }

  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Its good that you provided the correct code, but you can improve your answer by telling how it is correct and what was wrong in the code given in question

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ROW 50
#define MAX_COLUMN 50

char dest[MAX_ROW][MAX_COLUMN];

int str_rev_order(char *src)
{
    int idx = 0;
    int priv_idx = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for(i = 0;i<MAX_ROW; ++i) {
        memset(dest[i],0,MAX_COLUMN);
    }
    /* reset the counter */
    i = 0;
    while(src[i] != '\0') {
        if(idx >= MAX_ROW-1) {
            printf("Don't support more than %d substring.\n\r",MAX_ROW);
            return -1;
        }
        if(j >= MAX_COLUMN -1) {
            printf("Don't support string length more than %d.\n\r",MAX_COLUMN);
            return -1;
        }
        if(src[i] == ' ') {
            if(priv_idx == idx) {
                /* going to next row & reset the column counter*/
                idx ++;
                j = 0;
            }
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        *(*(dest + idx) + j) = src[i];
        i++;
        j++;
        priv_idx = idx;
    }
    return idx;

}

void print_rev_order(int idx) {
    int i;
    for (i = idx; i>=0; --i) {
        printf("%s\n\r",dest[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    char *src = "I am a boy";
    int idx = str_rev_order(src);
    print_rev_order(idx);
    return 0;
}
```